# for command to set a variable does not work

Tags: variables, batch-file, for-loop

I'm running this command and I don't see why it won't work

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (harry-boy) do set %%a:-==

echo %harry%

pause
```

And this is the result I get -

```
e:\6\1>setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

e:\6\1>for %a in (harry-boy) do set %a:-==

e:\6\1>set harry-boy:-==

e:\6\1>echo
ECHO is on.

e:\6\1>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I'm changing the hyphen sign to a equals sign then running the set command on that. I expect to see that the variable "harry" = "boy"??

Here is a simple test -

```
set file=play=here.mkv
set %file:==-%
echo %file%
pause
```

and I get this -

```
set file=play=here.mkv
==-%
 was unexpected at this time.

set %file:==-%
```

I thought I would get the new contents of file = play-here.mkv. Ok, I see that this makes the syntax wrong and the set command stops. So how do I change the = to a hyphen?

Comment: Your syntax is wrong in the set command, and you can't use a loop variable name in that way.  It has to be a variable name.

Comment: You have added more information - the replacement feature cannot replace an `=` sign.

Answer (score 1):

The string replacement format:

```
%var:old-string=new-string%
```

does NOT work on `for` replaceable parameters, just in Batch variables. The equivalent way for your example, using a variable instead, would be:

```
set a=harry-boy
set %a:-==%
echo %harry%
pause
```

Output:

```
C:>set a=harry-boy
C:>set harry=boy
C:>echo boy
boy
C:>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense.I'm trying something basic like your test and I can't see the error staring at it. Take a look in my original post for it.

Answer (score 0):

Easy soloution:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=-" %%a in ("harry-boy") do set %%a=%%b
Echo %harry%
```

And that should do your job for you. But it will only work with one `-` in the quote.

Comment: it will work with more `-`if you write `tokens=1,*` instead of `tokens=1,2` (`%%b` will be a string containing the rest of the line)

Answer (score 0):

`SET` will assign the value on the right of the first `=` to an environment variable named on the left.

Hence you would be assigning a value of `=` to a variable named `harry-boy:-` in BOTH cases.

You can verify this by executing

```
set harr
```

which will display any variable starting `harr`